# WCF [operationcontract] can be ignored when you use REST's webinvoke or webget?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetContent", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public List<Content> GetContent(string path) {
        return Utility.GetContent(path);
    }

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetContent", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public List<Content> GetContent(string path) {
    return Utility.GetContent(path);
}
```

Do these two methods function the same way or do they do anything different?  Looks like they both work for me..

Answer (score 0):

The OperationContractAttribute attribute declares that a method is an operation in a service contract. Only methods attributed with the OperationContractAttribute are exposed as service operations. A service contract without any methods marked with the OperationContractAttribute exposes no operations.